# NPM run serve - LocalStorage already defined as a built-in global variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, axios

Any example I downloaded which demonstrates the use of vue.js and axios runs into the following problem as I run 'npm run serve'

**'localStorage' already defined as a built-in global variable**

As I haven't changed anything in the code and the examples are used by many people, the error has to be on my side. It occurs wherever localStorage is used. The is no new declaration of it

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there any indication of which part of the build is reporting this error? e.g. Is it ESLint, Babel, ...?

Comment: @skirtle it is from eslint and its rule "no-redeclare". "Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js)"

Comment: Did you try add to your eslint config `globlas: {"localStorage": false}`

Comment: yeah right now and it works! thanks. but.... seems weird